# Java 1.8 generating error on installation to Windows XP, is it meaningful?

Tags: java

I installed Java 1.8 u102 today and it gave the warning that for Java to work "as expected" I needed to upgrade my operating system. I run Windows XP. I thought the whole point of Java was to have broad OS compatibility, including legacy operating systems?

Is this warning meaningful at all? What issues would running on XP cause?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html  Windows XP is no longer a supported operating system.  It is 16 years old.  Maybe time for an upgrade?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I know what it says. That is not my question. My question is: what functionality does not work?

Comment: Well, know knows?  I guess you can try it out and see what happens.

Comment: There is no meaningful answer to this; except for the fact that OS technology evolves and that Java follows trends, going as far back as reasonably possible. But Windows XP is now prehistory, and Oracle decided that supporting XP for the Java 8+ time frame was not worth the trouble. Upgrade your OS.

Comment: The best answer for this is: unexpected things may happen when running something on unsupported infrastructure. Or easier: Upgrade your OS. Using Windows XP nowadys is unsecure.

Comment: In my opinion Xp is the greatest version of windows ever developed by MS  , vista was an epic failure even 7 ... all these graphics and shiny bouncing transparent windows are useless luxury and a waist of hardware resources. almost all nowadays applications and OS try to keep the user away from knowing what is really going on his machine, for many reasons. they call it evolution and enhancement I call it lobotomy to create consumers and clicking gurus (with all my respect to new people ,this site is full of stuff like my button doesn't show ).sorry I had this on the heart :p

Comment: @whyn0t I consider anything after XP to basically be spyware.